# Is it possible to use a Ruby gem in an iOS project written in Swift?

Tags: ios, ruby, swift, xcode

I am interested in reusing a ruby gem in my iOS project that is written in Swift. Is this possible? Or do I need to re-write it in Swift?

Comment: what is the ruby gem exactly ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You just need to embed a Ruby execution engine in your app.

Comment: it would have been more helpful if you mention some details about embedding the execution engine

Comment: I think You are looking for this https://github.com/carsonmcdonald/ios-ruby-embedded